# wordpress show same posts in each page pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

I made pagination but, it not work corrent, in each page showing same posts.

Code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'post', 'kalba' => 'Lietuviu', 'posts_per_page' => 2) );?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>
        <h2 class="title"><a href ="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php echo $query->post->post_title;?></a></h2>
        <div class="date"><?php echo mysql2date('Y-m-d', $query->post->post_date);?></div>
        <div class="post"><p><?php echo $query->post->post_content;?></p></div>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <? $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
        echo paginate_links( array( 'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                            'format'  => '?paged=%#%',
                            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                            'total'   => $query->max_num_pages,
                            'end_size'=> 1,
                            'mid_size'=> 10 ) );?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I can't found problem, maybe problem is that I using "taxonomy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are executing the same query over and over:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'post', 'kalba' => 'Lietuviu', 'posts_per_page' => 2) );?>
```

You need to set an [offset](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query_posts-offset-and-pagination) in the WP_Query array: `'offset'=> 2`

We can calculate the offset by using a global variable that wordpress uses called `$page` by using a simple equation: `$offset = ($page -1) * $post_per_page;`

so your final WP_QUERY should look something like:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'post', 'kalba' => 'Lietuviu', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'offset'=> (($page -1) * 2) ) );?>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that you are calling `if ( have_posts() )` to early. You need to determine if the WP_QUERY comes back with a response before you call that function. Move you query statement above the if block

Comment: Does the URL end with something like "page/2"?

Comment: hmm, the only other thing that i can mention, is that if you are creating your own pagination, then you are probably going to have to parse the URL out, to determine the page number, then set it on it own. That's the only other thing that I can think of.

Comment: thanks bro, i solv problem I add ` <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;?> `   `'paged' =>$paged `

Comment: oh nice well done. now i now for the future. the help goes both ways